# Do your villagers remember you when they move out or not?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I keep getting different answers, and none of them seem specific to Animal Crossing New Leaf, so I'm not sure if my villagers who move out will remember me or not. What determines it? I know that they'll remember you if they move to a friend's town, but what if they just move out? I'm getting really frustrated trying to find the answer since I've searched everywhere on the net and none answer my question.

Comment: Interesting question...though note with 300+ villagers it's now quite unlikely that the same villager will move back in, so it's probably pretty hard to come by this info (though not impossible)

Comment: That saddens me. :c I wish that the developers at least could give us this information. You would think with the latest AC game they'd give the villagers the ability to remember you. I hope that's the case.

Comment: Oh it's possible they do; it's just very unlikely you'll get the same villager again by pure chance

Comment: Thanks to a group of friends we are testing this now. I will respond when we get a definite answer

Comment: Thank you so so so much. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Well, they do send a letter to you. Not a gift, though.

Answer (score 3):

I moved as a citizen to my own town in new leaf, I visited the town I moved from and they recognized me, it's not a lot but its something.

Answer (score 2):

They do remember you.

When a villager moves out of your town, they'll usually **come back to your town** for some other reasons, such as *shopping*, *partying at* **Club LOL**, or to do something else.

Comment: I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you meet the villager after they move out. If it's on your main street, then yes, but if you reset your town and then the villager moves into the new town then they won't. I had Jacques in my old town, then reset it, and he moved into that one and he had no idea who I was. If you see the villager that moved out in a friend's town they will remember you. It all depends on where you see the villager afterwards.